# List comprehension while plotting graph from several columns

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot a line graph from several columns

```
ax = sns.lineplot(data=mt, 
                  x= ['pt'],
                  y = [c for c in mt.columns if c not in ['pt']],
                  dashes=False)
```

The response I am getting is

```
ValueError: Length of list vectors must match length of `data` when both are used, but `data` has length 13 and the vector passed to `x` has length 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

Seaborn's prefers data in [long form](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data), which can be created via `pd.melt()`. A [wide form](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#wide-form-data) dataframe is supported if you create an index (and the data isn't too complex).

Here is a simple example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

mt = pd.DataFrame({'pt': np.arange(100),
                   'y1': np.random.randn(100).cumsum(),
                   'y2': np.random.randn(100).cumsum(),
                   'y3': np.random.randn(100).cumsum()})
sns.set()
ax = sns.lineplot(data=mt.set_index('pt'), dashes=True)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.lineplot from wide dataframe]